# Plotting multiple figures with matplotlib on Atom IDE

Tags: python, matplotlib, atom-editor

I can successfully plot using python and matplotlib on the Atom IDE. However, if I plot two or more figures, only a single figure window appears with the first plot and to see the other figures I must close the initial window in which case the next figure will generate and display. I cannot see all the figures simultaneously I have to close the figure tab one by one to see the different figures. Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Ok I found the mistake, I must only call plt.show() once at the end of the script

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question yourself, but if I may : try looking into subplots. ;)

It will allow you to draw multiple things, on separate plot, but on the same figure.